# TYPO3 v10 render page media image in fluid

Tags: typoscript, fluid, typo3-10.x

I'm trying to add page resource media images to the MenuAbstract.html template in TYPO3 v10. It just won't work. I don't get any output. I tried adding the following to the fluid template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pageImage" />
```

The whole template would look like this:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">

    <f:if condition="{menu}">
        <ul>
            <f:for each="{menu}" as="page">
                <li>
                    <a href="{page.link}"{f:if(condition: page.target, then: ' target="{page.target}"')} title="{page.title}">
                        <span>{page.title}</span>
                    </a>

                    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pageImage" />

                    <f:if condition="{page.data.resource}">
                        <f:format.html>{page.data.media}</f:format.html>
                    </f:if>
                    <f:if condition="{page.data.abstract}">
                        <f:format.html>{page.data.abstract}</f:format.html>
                    </f:if>
                </li>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
    </f:if>


</f:section>
</html>
```

The TypoScript objects looks like this:

```
lib.pageImage = FILES 
lib.pageImage { 
  references { 
    table = pages 
    uid.data = uid
    fieldName = media
  } 
  renderObj = IMAGE 
  renderObj {
    file { 
      import.data = file:current:uid 
      treatIdAsReference = 1 
      width = 150c 
      height = 150c 
    } 
    altText.data = file:current:alternative
    titleText.data = file:current:title
  } 
  maxItems = 1
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the input data?

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pageImage" data="{page}"/>
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html) to cObject